# How to create CSV from list "by key"

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, csv

I try to create a CSV from this list:

```
[
 ['', '0'], 
 ['user_pos', '1/300'], 
 ['timestamp', '2018-05-13 11:51:28'], 
 ['user_followers', '251'], 
 ['post_link', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BitpY7rAs-H/?tagged=bio'], 
 ['user_relationship_ratio', '0.66'], ['user_following', '381'], 
 ['tag_info', '  desired amount: 300  |  top postsdisabled: 9  |  
  possible posts: 4514653'], 
 ['Likes', 22],

 ['user', 'frichticook_'], 
 ['post_desc', "Bonjour..."], 
 ['tag_pos', 'Tag1/3'], 
 ['img_url', u'https://scontent-cdg2']
]
```

Where 'user_pos' 'timestamp' etc are the headers of the columns?

Thank you in advance

I already tried this:

```
def WriteListToCSV(csv_file,csv_columns,data_list):
  try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', 
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        writer.writerow(csv_columns)
        for data in data_list:
            writer.writerow(data)
  except IOError as (errno, strerror):
        print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror))    
  return
```

But it give me something like this:

[image]

Comment: no @sP_ I want the first value 'timestamp' etc to be the column headers and the values like '2018-05-13 11:51:28' to be the rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should transpose the list (swap the rows and columns):

```
with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', 
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for data in zip(*data_list): # Where the magic happens
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: i was about to post exact same thing ... :)

Comment: But, thing is, i don't see the point of creating csv with just two rows, one with header and the other values. its good if there are multiple rows, but based on the image, it looks not so useful

Comment: @InAFlash The solution works for any number of rows.

Comment: Yes, i agree it works. i was mentioning about the question

Comment: there will be more rows, thanks for the answers need to order everything cause the values don't match witht the headers for now :/

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce I used the same options as the OP.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce If the OP wants the Excel dialect, why not ask for it explicitly?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Because the defaults change over time? Why is it an issue at all?

Comment: @DyZ It's unnecessary

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Fine. Don't use it.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce, i think i should agree with DyZ, because..defaults change over time. and he mentioned it because he wanted the user to know what's the default

Comment: @DyZ thank you for your reply. Unfortunately when the code runs with more than one entry, the CSV who's created is made on a single row rather than 1,2,3 and so on :/  I think it's because of the list I use to insert data but do you have an idea on how or what I need to change on this list to get a CSV with serveral rows?